# repcached purge cache

Tags: memcached

I have 3 servers all running repcached (memcached patch to support replication)
Is there a way that I can invalidate the whole cache on all servers at once?

Right now, I first stop all servers and then start them one by one

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send this command to the server,

```
echo "flush_all" | nc 127.0.0.1 11211
```

Comment: Hi. Say I run the command on server 1 and then go and run the command on server 2. Won't server 1 begin to replicate data immediately from server 2? So by the time I issue the command to server 2, server1 will have gotten stale data? Is my assumption wrong? Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but where exactly in the page you mention, there is a reference to cache invalidation?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake, you only need to send it to one server :)